# How to get all groups from Dask DataFrameGroupBy, if I have more then one group by fields?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

how can I get all unique groups in Dask from grouped data frame?
Let's say, we have the following code:

```
g = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Day'])
```

I have to iterate through all groups and process the data within the groups. 
My idea was to get all unique value combinations and then iterate through the collection and call e.g.

```
g.get_group((2018,01,12)).compute()
```

for each of them... which is not going to be fast, but hopefully will work..

In Spark/Scala I can achieve smth like this using the following approach:

```
val res = myDataFrame.groupByKey(x => groupFunctionWithX(X)).mapGroups((key,iter) => {
 process group with all the child records
} )
```

I am wondering, what is the best way to implement smth like this using  Dask/Python?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Best, Michael

UPDATE

I have tried the following in python with pandas:

```
df = pd.read_parquet(path, engine='pyarrow')
g = df.groupby(('Year', 'Month', 'Day'))
g.apply(lambda x: print(x.Year[0], x.Month[0], x.Day[0], x.count()[0]))
```

And this was working perfectly fine. Afterwards, I have tried the same with Dask:

```
df2 = dd.read_parquet(path, engine='pyarrow')
g2 = df2.groupby(('Year', 'Month', 'Day'))
g2.apply(lambda x: print(x.Year[0], x.Month[0], x.Day[0], x.count()[0]))
```

This has led me to the following error:

```
ValueError: Metadata inference failed in `groupby.apply(lambda)`.
```

Any ideas what went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Computing one group at a time is likely to be slow.  Instead I recommend using groupby-apply

```
df.groupby([...]).apply(func)
```

Like Pandas, the user-defined function `func` should expect a Pandas dataframe that has all rows corresponding to that group, and should return either a Pandas dataframe, a Pandas Series, or scalar.

Getting one group at a time can be cheap if your data is indexed by the grouping column

```
df = df.set_index('date')
part = df.loc['2018-05-01'].compute()
```

Given that you're grouping by a few columns though I'm not sure how well this will work.

Comment: The question is, what can I do inside the apply function? Can I save just the values of grouping columns? Or do I have access to all underlying rows within the group?

Comment: I have also tried doing smth like g.apply(lambda x: (x.Year,x.Month,x.Day)), but it's not really working..

Comment: I've edited the answer above with more information.  This works just like pandas groupby-apply.

Comment: Thank you for your example. I have tried it in pandas and dask. It works in pandas perfectly fine, but is not working in dask at all.

Comment: @MRocklin. I found several questions and answers related to dask, and tried to implement a method on this particular problem; but I cannot seem to figure out. Can you please look into this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178441/merge-multiple-dataframe-using-dask-and-then-write-files-with-groupby

Comment: Note groupby + apply does not have the same behavior in Dask vs Pandas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60725384/145349